# Help about javascript removeclass

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sign up form

```
<form class="sform" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>login/create_member" >
                <div class="rleft">User Type <span style="color:red">*</span></div>
                <div class="fright">
                <select name="role" id="role" onchange="rToggle()">
                <option value="1">Company</option>
                                <option value="2">Student</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="rleft">Username <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="20" title="Username" class="rtb" value="<?php echo set_value('username');?>">
                <?php echo form_error('username');?></div>
                <div class="rleft">Password <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="20" title="Password" class="rtb" value="<?php echo set_value('password');?>">
                <?php echo form_error('password');?></div>
                <div class="rleft">Confirm&nbsp;Password <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                    <input name="password2" type="password" id="cpassword" size="20" title="Confirm Password" class="rtb" value="<?php echo set_value('password2');?>">
                <?php echo form_error('password2');?></div>
                <div class="rleft">Last Name <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                    <input name="lname" type="text" id="firstname" title="First Name" class="rtb" value="<?php echo set_value('lname');?>">
                <?php echo form_error('lname');?></div>
                <div class="rleft">First Name <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                    <input name="fname" type="text" id="lastname" title="Last Name" class="rtb" value="<?php echo set_value('fname');?>">
                <?php echo form_error('fname');?></div>
                <div class="rleft">Middle Initial <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                    <input name="mname" type="text" id="middlename" size="5" title="Middle Initial" value="<?php echo set_value('mname');?>">
                <?php echo form_error('mname');?></div>
                <div class="rleft">E-mail Address <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                    <input NAME="email_add" type="text" id="email" title="Email" class="rtb" value="<?php echo set_value('email_add');?>">
                <?php echo form_error('email_add');?></div>
                <div id="companydetails">
                    <div class="rleft">Position/Title <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                        <input NAME="cposition" type="text" id="cposition" title="Position/Title" class="tb">
                    </div>
                    <div class="rleft">Company Name <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                        <input NAME="cname" type="text" id="cname" title="Company Name" class="tb">
                    </div>
                    <div class="rleft">Office Address <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                        <input NAME="caddress" type="text" id="caddress" title="Office Address" class="tb">
                    </div>
                    <div class="rleft">Contact Number <span style="color:red">*</span></div><div class="fright">
                        <input NAME="ccontact_no" type="text" id="ccontact_no" title="Office Address" class="tb">
                    </div>                    
                </div>                
                <div class="rleft">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="fright">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" id="regsubmit">
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" ></div>



            </form>
```

and my javascript function

```
function rToggle()
{
    if ($('#role').val() == '1') {
        $('#companydetails').hide();
        $('#cposition').removeClass('rtb');    
        $('#cname').removeClass('rtb');            
        $('#caddress').removeClass('rtb');    
        $('#ccontanct_no').removeClass('rtb');    
    }
    else {
        $('#companydetails').show();
        $('#cposition').addClass('rtb');    
        $('#cname').addClass('rtb');            
        $('#caddress').addClass('rtb');    
        $('#ccontanct_no').addClass('rtb');    
    }
}
```

This works like this:.

If I chose 2(Student), it will only show the this fields: username, pass, cpass, fname, mname, email_address

If I chose 1(company), it will show all fields including the fields above and cname, cposition, caddress, ccontact_no

Now the problem is when I fill up all fields then chose 2(students) it will still save all post data in my db. What I want is even if I fill up the all fields then chose 2(student) those in companydetails must now be save.! 
Anyone know to fix this? or expert in javascript?

Comment: You are using JQuery, right? If you are, then please include it in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should add PHP to your tags.

But to answer your question: this is a server side issue. Solving it with JavaScript isn't enough.
In your PHP code, wherever you write your INSERT or UPDATE query, you must check for role being 2 and not add your extra fields if it's not.

To avoid having the extra fields being passed to your server when unnecessary, you can update your code like this:

```
if ($('#role').val() == '1') {
    // ...

    $('#cposition').disabled = false;
    // etc. for the other inputs
}
else {
    // ...

    $('#cname').disabled = true;
    // etc.
}
```